# Propogation of singularity for the 3D wave eqaution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, singularity

A book I'm reading ("An Introduction to PDE" by Pinchover and Rubinstien) compares the propagation of singularities in 1D wave equations and in 3D wave equations.

Authors states:

> We proved (in an earlier discussion) that even when (1D wave equation)
> do have singular points, the solution is singular in exactly the same
> way, and the singularity propagate along characteristic curves

So far, so good. They proceed to discuss the 3D case:

> The situation is different in the three-dimensional case, as smooth
> initial data might develop singularities over time.

To back those statements up, writers supply an example:

Given a wave equation, with initial condition (in polar coordinates):
$$
u_{tt} - \Delta u = 0 \\
u(r, 0) = f(r) \\
u_{t}(r, 0) = 0 \\
$$
Where:

$$
f(r) = \begin{cases}
1 & r \leq 1, \\
0 & r > 1
\end{cases}
$$

Mark $\tilde{f}$ as the even expansions of the function $f$, one obtains a radial solution:

$$
u(r,t) = \frac{1}{2r}[(r+t)\tilde{f}(r+t) + (r-t)\tilde{f}(r-t)]
$$

And now to the actual point:
$$
u(r,t) \xrightarrow[r \to 0]{} f(t) + tf'(t)
$$
(we've used the fact that $\tilde{f}$ is even and thus $\tilde{f}'$ is odd)

This function has a singularity at t=1, as pointed by the authors. They state:

> ... the above formula implies that the solution blows up at t=1 ... The
> reason for that spontaneous creation of singularities is geometric ...
> the singularity that started it's life as a 2D object (a sphere) later
> turned into a zero-dimensional object (a point)

Stuff I do not understand:

1. This is not a case of "smooth initial data developing a singularity over time" or a "spontaneous creation of singularities". The initial data is obviously not smooth. Is this phenomena (creation of singularities over time) possible? May you kindly point me to an example?
2. I think I can see where the authors are going - I'd expect waves propagating from the boundary of a circular pool to clash in the middle and make a mess. However, I think this is not completely clear from the example. Is my intuition correct? Can anyone supply me with a short analysis for such case, or a reference to such analysis?

Many thanks!